# Minecraft: Issues concerning chunk refreshing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft: Java Edition version 1.11 on PC. I was designing a flying machine with observers and pistons when I observed this bug.

Whenever the flying machine sets off, it creates randomly, some observers and pistons, throughout its path. These components can be broken but will not drop as an item.

Is this problem related to some issues in chunk loading/refreshing?

Reloading the save removes all these randomly created components.

I've uploaded some screenshots of these instances

[image][image]

Is there a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Why are you in 1.11?

Comment: The reason I'm playing 1.11 is because I'm not getting a decent fps on the current version.

Comment: Try 1.12.2, it has better performance than 1.13 and 1.14 and might already contain a fix for this.

Comment: I'll try it, aren't there any official patches or fix?

Comment: You mean bug fixes applied retroactively to past versions? No, that's what new versions are for.

Comment: I tried version 1.12.2, but the issue still persists!

Answer (score 1):

These aren't actual blocks, these are only visual bugs, so-called "ghost blocks". To test, you can for example try to place a block on them and you'll see that it instead places the block where the ghost block was. A lot of bugs that caused ghost blocks were fixed since 1.11, so I recommended playing a more recent version.